# For onclick, when to use `onclick="confirmOnSubmit()` vs `onclick="confirmOnSubmit`

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to HTML and JavaScript. I have seen `onclick` been assigned to function with following parentheses `onclick="confirmOnSubmit()` and functions without following parentheses `onclick="confirmOnSubmit`.

I was just wondering what is the difference between the two? When should I use one over the other?

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitID" onclick="confirmOnSubmit()"/>
```

Comment: Where have you seen the latter?

Comment: for example, document.getElementById("buttonID2").onmouseover = changeColorOnMouseOver vs             document.getElementById("buttonID2").onmouseover = changeColorOnMouseOver();
. where changeColorOnMouseOver is the name of a function

Comment: That's entirely different to your **HTML** examples of `onclick="confirmOnSubmit()"` vs `onclick="confirmOnSubmit"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using parentheses after a function name means **invoking** that function.However, using it without a parentheses just means the function itself.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitID" onclick="confirmOnSubmit()"/>
```

so in your example, it is basically saying that whenever the submit btn is clicked, invoke the confirmOnSubmit function.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitID"/>

document.getElementById('submitID').onclick=confirmOnSubmit
```

however, in the above example, we don't want to call the function at that moment, we just want to assign a reference, so that it can be called later on when the event happens.

hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much! so confusing for a beginner lol